# Linear Transformation between Isomorphic Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Suppose $f:V\to W$ is a linear transformation, and that there exists a
>   basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ for $V$ such that
>   $\{f(v_1),\ldots,f(v_n)\}$ is a basis for $W$. Prove that $f$ is an
>   isomorphism.

Intuitively, this makes perfect sense. Since basis is an exhaustive representation of every unique vector in a vector space, if a linear transformation maps one basis to another it should be an isomorphism because it indicates some sort of equality between the two vector spaces. But I'm having difficulty putting this into a formal proof.

Comment: *"basis is an exhaustive representation of every unique vector in a vector space"*: this doesn't quite make sense as written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

Define f(v1) = w1

f(v2) = w2
....

f(vn) = wn

since these are a basis for W, this means f is onto.

since dimV = dimImT + dimNullT

dimNullT = 0 (if dimW is greater than dimV then T can't be onto) then T is injective.

also if dimW is less than dimV than T is not injective. Then dimV = dimW

Then there exists an isomorphism between V and W and T is such since it is injective, onto, and therefore invertible.

Answer (score 1):

We are given that $f$ is linear; we just need to prove that it is both injective and surjective.

**Injectivity:** we need to show that if $f(x) = f(y)$, then $x = y$.  That is, if
$$
f(a_1 v_1 + \cdots + a_n v_n) = f(b_1 v_1 + \cdots + b_n v_n)
$$
then
$$
a_1 v_1 + \cdots + a_n v_n = b_1 v_1 + \cdots + b_n v_n
$$

**Surjectivity:** If $y \in W$, then we can write
$$
y = a_1 f(v_1) + \cdots + a_n f(v_n)
$$
find an $x \in V$ such that $f(x) = y$.